# Android profiler doesn't recognize running device in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, leakcanary, android-profiler, android-device-monitor

I run my app with `Android Profiler`, but it doesn't show anything in `Android Profiler` and doesn't recognize the device.

[image]
**Note :**

1 : Android Studio is the latest version

2 : I already checked the "Enable advancement profiling for older devices"

Comment: Try doing this `Android Studio -> File -> Invalid cache and restart`

Comment: I did that but it didn't work

Comment: Seems like a bug on Android Studio side. I recommend you open a bug, including the `idea.log` file and the device and api versions

Answer (score 0):

You run the Android Studio profiler separately, is this your required option? If not, you can launch Android Studio with your project, open the profiler window from below and click on the green bug that is next to the green triangle.

Comment: Its still doesn't work

Comment: @NimaKhalili, your EditFragmentOperationPositive.java has four errors, can you fix them and try to run the android profiler with a **green bug**?

Comment: The errors are for API level. The application is work perfect.

Comment: @NimaKhalili, try to fix the errors at the api level, run the build and launch of the application using android studio, and the android profiler should detect the processes/devices to connect

Comment: I used in a new project and still didn't work

Comment: @NimaKhalili, any exceptions?

Comment: I remember a few months ago, after the Android Studio updated, the run window no longer works too. I think my android studio has a basic problem